# If $X_n, n\ge 1$ are independent r.v.'s, then $\sup_n X_n<\infty a.s.$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X_n>a)<\infty$ for some $a$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

If $X_n, n\ge 1$ are independent r.v.'s, then $sup_n X_n<\infty a.s.$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X_n>a)<\infty$ for some $a$

So far I have

(<=): Assume $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X_n>a)>\infty$. By Borel-Cantelli lemma,

$$P(\limsup_n X_n>a)=P(X_n>a, i.o.)=0$$

But I want this in the form $P(\sup_nX_n=\infty)=0$ which is the same as $\sup_nX_n<\infty$ a.s.. How do I get to the next step?

---

For the converse direction, if $\sup_n X_n<\infty$ a.s., then $P(\sup X_n<\infty)=1$ implies

$\sum_n P(\sup_n X_n<\infty)=\infty$

By Borel-Cantelli (ii), $P(\sup X_n<\infty \text{ i.o.})=1$

How do I get this in the form $P(X_n>a)$?

Answer (score 2):

To continue in the direction you have started, think about a sequence of real numbers $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. If there exists $K$ such that $x_n > K$ for only finitely many $n$, then can we have $\sup x_n = \infty$?

Comment: So if there is only $x_n>K$ for finitely many $n$, then $P(\sup X_n=\infty)=0$ directly?

Comment: For the converse part of the proof, I used Borel-Cantelli again and got $P(\sup X_n<\infty i.o.)=1$. How would this become $\sum P(X_n>a)<\infty$?

Comment: The reason I suggested you consider the above is that based on what you have so far, you know that $\{X_n > a i.o.\}$ has probability $0$, so the complement of this set, $\{X_n \leq a \mathrm{eventually}\}$ has probability 1. So if we pick an $\omega \in \Omega$, $(X_n(w))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of real numbers with the property described in my post. Hopefully you can see that this sequence must be bounded, and so has finite supremum.

Comment: Is there a theorem that says if $x_n>K$ for only finitely many $n$ then $x_n$ must be bounded above?

Comment: if $x_n>K$ for only finitely many $n$, then $x_n$ converges and is bounded above with prob 1?

Comment: The reason I'm talking about a sequence of real numbers in my post is so that you don't have to worry about anything probabilistic for the moment. If $x_n > K$ for only finitely many $n$ (as an example, let's suppose that only $x_2, x_{89}$ and $x_{385}$ are bigger than K) then it must be the case that the whole sequence is bounded above (in the example, the whole sequence is bounded above by the number $\max\{x_2,x_{89},x_{385}\}$ - can you see why?). Once you are happy with what's going on with a sequence of real numbers, you can then attempt to finish the first direction of the proof.

Comment: ohh! i see now, thank you so much!