# $X_n$ are independent rv's. $\sup X_n <\infty$ implies there exist $A$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X_n>A)<\infty$

Tags: probability-theory

$X_n, n\ge 1$ are independent random variables. Suppose $\sup_n X_n<\infty$ almost surely. Show that there exist $A\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X_n>A)<\infty$ for some $A$

Actually this is an if and only if statement, but I am stuck only in this part. Upon searching I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670044/if-x-n-n-ge-1-are-independent-r-v-s-then-sup-n-x-n-infty-a-s-if-and-on) post. However it doesn't help me much to prove this direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose it is not true, then for any $K \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n > K) = \infty$.

By Borel-Cantelli lemma, this means that  $\limsup X_n(\omega) \geq K$ for $\omega \in \Omega_K$ where $P(\Omega_K) = 1$.

Take $\Omega' = \cap_K \Omega_K$, it's easy to see $P(\Omega') = 1$. Then remark that for $\omega \in \Omega'$ $\limsup X_n(\omega) = +\infty$